# How to retrieve accidentally deleted data from within a Google Sheets file on a private Facebook Group - please help

Tags: google-sheets

Someone accidentally deleted the data within a shared Google Sheets document on our Facebook group. Is there any way we can get it back i.e. revert to a previous version of the document? Is this stored anywhere or would it be up to us to have a backup of the file somewhere? Would it be in their temporary internet files and if so, how would we find it?

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets automatically maintains full version history. To recover a previous version, choose **File > Version history > See version history**.